# MouseMove event prevents the MouseRightButtonUp event in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, events, mouseevent

I have drawn some lines using DrawingVisual. Now I'm trying to implement a simple hit testing.

When the mouse pointer moves over a line I'm redrawing it with twice its thickness to give the user a sense of highlighting (Magenta line in the image below)

[image]

This works very well until I also implement a `MouseRightButtonUp` event. I want to show a messagebox when the user right clicks the line. But somehow while the mouse is over the line and the line is highlighted, the `MouseRightButtonUp` event **does not raise** at all. What could be the problem?

```
MouseMove += OnMouseMove;
MouseRightButtonUp += OnMouseRightButtonUp;

private void OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var p = e.GetPosition(Window);

    // Check if the mouse hit any lines and redraw

    ReDraw();

}

void OnMouseRightButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    // Check if any line is hit and show the message box
    if (lineHit)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You hit the line!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Try the `PreviewMouseRightButtonUp` tunneling event.

Comment: @dymanoid I did, the same result. When I remove the MouseMove event every thing goes back to normal.

Comment: What control are you hooking up the `MouseMove` and `MouseRightButtonUp`, because I tried it with a simple application and both works fine.

Comment: @III The `Border` control. Can you possibly send that application to me?

Comment: I just tried to debug it, it seems it gets in a loop in the `OnMouseMove` method, nothing special in this file only that I redraw the lines, maybe that triggers the mousemove again?